# Hibernate firing a large number of select queries while saving associated objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate fires one select query for each of the associated object that it is trying to persist. If there are 5000 associated objects then 5000 selects followed by 5000 inserts!!!

This is leading to performance issues. Can any one please shed some light on why hibernate is doing so or what configuration below is leading to this. Thanks.

Below are the sqls being fired by hibernate while saving a FighterjetDO object, note in this sample there are 5 select queries for 5 inserts that hibernate is firing for the associated object set FighterjetMissionsDO:

```
Hibernate: select max(jet_id) from fighterjet
Hibernate: select fighterjet_.mission_id, fighterjet_.JET_ID, fighterjet_.name as name1_ from fighterjetmissions fighterjet_ where fighterjet_.mission_id=? and fighterjet_.JET_ID=?
Hibernate: select fighterjet_.mission_id, fighterjet_.JET_ID, fighterjet_.name as name1_ from fighterjetmissions fighterjet_ where fighterjet_.mission_id=? and fighterjet_.JET_ID=?
Hibernate: select fighterjet_.mission_id, fighterjet_.JET_ID, fighterjet_.name as name1_ from fighterjetmissions fighterjet_ where fighterjet_.mission_id=? and fighterjet_.JET_ID=?
Hibernate: select fighterjet_.mission_id, fighterjet_.JET_ID, fighterjet_.name as name1_ from fighterjetmissions fighterjet_ where fighterjet_.mission_id=? and fighterjet_.JET_ID=?
Hibernate: select fighterjet_.mission_id, fighterjet_.JET_ID, fighterjet_.name as name1_ from fighterjetmissions fighterjet_ where fighterjet_.mission_id=? and fighterjet_.JET_ID=?
Hibernate: insert into fighterjet (name, max_speed, country, jet_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fighterjetmissions (name, mission_id, JET_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fighterjetmissions (name, mission_id, JET_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fighterjetmissions (name, mission_id, JET_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fighterjetmissions (name, mission_id, JET_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fighterjetmissions (name, mission_id, JET_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Below are the domain objects and their hbms :

FighterjetDO :

```
public class FighterjetDO implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer jetId;

    private String name;

    private Integer maxSpeed;

    private String country;

    private Set<FighterjetMissionsDO> fighterjetMissionsDOSet;

   // Setters and getters.


}
```

FighterjetDO HBM :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.man.fighterjet.FighterjetDO" table="fighterjet">
        <id name="jetId" type="int" column="jet_id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <property name="maxSpeed">
            <column name="max_speed" />
        </property>
        <property name="country">
            <column name="country" />
        </property>

        <set name="fighterjetMissionsDOSet" lazy="true" table="fighterjetmissions" fetch="join" cascade="save-update" sort="unsorted" inverse="true">
            <key column="JET_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="com.man.fighterjet.FighterjetMissionsDO" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

FighterjetMissionsDO :

```
public class FighterjetMissionsDO implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer missionId;

    private String name;

    private FighterjetDO fighterjetDO;

    // Setters and getters.

}
```

FighterjetMissionsDO HBM :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.man.fighterjet.FighterjetMissionsDO" table="fighterjetmissions">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="missionId" column="mission_id" type="integer" />

            <key-many-to-one name="fighterjetDO" class="com.man.fighterjet.FighterjetDO">
               <column name="JET_ID"/>
            </key-many-to-one>
       </composite-id>

        <property name="name">
            <column name="name"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Test Code to populate and persist :

```
        FighterjetDAO fighterjetDAO = new FighterjetDAO();


        Set<FighterjetMissionsDO> fighterjetMissionsDOSet = new HashSet<FighterjetMissionsDO>();

        FighterjetDO newFighterjetDO = new FighterjetDO();
        newFighterjetDO.setName("F22");
        newFighterjetDO.setMaxSpeed(1000);
        newFighterjetDO.setCountry("USA");

        FighterjetMissionsDO fighterjetMissionsDO1 = new FighterjetMissionsDO();
        fighterjetMissionsDO1.setMissionId(101);
        fighterjetMissionsDO1.setName("HIbernate");
        fighterjetMissionsDO1.setFighterjetDO(newFighterjetDO);
        fighterjetMissionsDOSet.add(fighterjetMissionsDO1);


        FighterjetMissionsDO fighterjetMissionsDO2 = new FighterjetMissionsDO();
        fighterjetMissionsDO2.setMissionId(102);
        fighterjetMissionsDO2.setName("HIbernate2");
        fighterjetMissionsDO2.setFighterjetDO(newFighterjetDO);
        fighterjetMissionsDOSet.add(fighterjetMissionsDO2);


        FighterjetMissionsDO fighterjetMissionsDO3 = new FighterjetMissionsDO();
        fighterjetMissionsDO3.setMissionId(103);
        fighterjetMissionsDO3.setName("HIbernate3");
        fighterjetMissionsDO3.setFighterjetDO(newFighterjetDO);
        fighterjetMissionsDOSet.add(fighterjetMissionsDO3);


        FighterjetMissionsDO fighterjetMissionsDO4 = new FighterjetMissionsDO();
        fighterjetMissionsDO4.setMissionId(104);
        fighterjetMissionsDO4.setName("HIbernate4");
        fighterjetMissionsDO4.setFighterjetDO(newFighterjetDO);
        fighterjetMissionsDOSet.add(fighterjetMissionsDO4);


        FighterjetMissionsDO fighterjetMissionsDO5 = new FighterjetMissionsDO();
        fighterjetMissionsDO5.setMissionId(105);
        fighterjetMissionsDO5.setName("HIbernate5");
        fighterjetMissionsDO5.setFighterjetDO(newFighterjetDO);
        fighterjetMissionsDOSet.add(fighterjetMissionsDO5);



        newFighterjetDO.setFighterjetMissionsDOSet(fighterjetMissionsDOSet);

        fighterjetDAO.createJet(newFighterjetDO);
```

FighterjetDAO :

```
 public void createJet(FighterjetDO fighterjetDO) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(fighterjetDO);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Hibernate is trying to perform optimistic locking.

If you add a `version` column it will be able to perform a more efficient `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` operation.

Comment: Thanks a ton Steve C. I would never thought of that. You are absolutely right!!! Thanks again. Do you have any good pointers on optimistic locking of hibernate - this behavior in particular.

Comment: There is extensive documentation to be found at [Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/)

Comment: Thanks. Also is there any other way to turn of locking. I tried lock-mode="none" which lead to hibernate xml parsing error.